# Netsuite External Url Call

Tags: javascript, http, netsuite, suitescript

I am Trying to call  External URL From Suitelet its throwing 406 Error.

```
var user_name = ‘username’;
var password = ‘password’;
var url=”Url”;
var auth = nlapiEncrypt(user_name+’:’+password,’base64′);

var headers = new Array();
headers[“Content-Type”] = “application/json”;
headers[“Authorization”] = ‘Basic ‘+auth+”;
headers[“Token”] = ‘abcdddd-djfjjff-djd/dkdkd’;

var token_res=nlapiRequestURL(url, null,headers);
var token_response_XML = token_res.getBody();
nlapiLogExecution(‘DEBUG’, ‘token_response_XML’, token_response_XML);
```

Anyone Suggest Please?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick Google search (it's been a LONG time since I've seen that error code), it looks like your other system is not returning the data in the manner that is expected.  I would suggest testing with something like the chrome ARC (Advanced REST Client) extension so that you can see the entire process and get it all perfected.  Here is the page I read up on 406 errors to refresh my memory.

[406 Not Acceptable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)

Comment: Yes, I tried with ARC, Postman, SoapUI there it is working by using suiteLet was getting that error.

Comment: Try adding those accept headers to your headers array.  That might force NetSuite to accept them.

Comment: Can you try sending the data somewhere else?  Like a custom endpoint that does not reply?  Then you could at least see if NetSuite is altering the data?